# finding constant in CDF

Tags: probability

CMD of RV $A$ is :

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf F_{A}(a)
 & =\begin{cases}0 & : a<0 \\  1a\over {2} & : 0\le a<1  \\ c & : a\ge 1\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

a) What is the value of the constant c? 
b) What is $P[{1\over2} < A\le 1]$  ?
c)What is $P[{1\over2} < A< 1]$?
d)What is $P[A>2]?$

**Question $a$ here:** How to find constant $c$ ? (i have no idea)
To find question $b$,  $c$ and $d$ it seems i need to find Constat $c$ firstly 
 i tried to find 
 **Question $b$ here:** 
$P[{1\over2} < A\le 1] = F_A({1\over2})- F_A(1) = {a\over 2} - c$ (here, do i have to find $a$ ? or just leave it by) 
 **in Question c:**
 
$P[{1\over2} < A< 1] = F_A({1\over2})- F_A(1) - P[A=1] = {a\over 2} - c$ 
 How i can express $P[A=1]$ as $F[X]$ ? 
**in question $d$:** 
 $P[A>2]=1-P[A\le 2]=F[2]=c$ 
 This is how i far go. I`m bloody beginner in Probability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

For part (a), by definition of the CDF in general $$\lim_{a \to \infty}F_{A}(a) = 1$$

For part (b) you have $P(1/2 < A \leq 1) = F_{A}(a = 1) - F_{A}(a = 1/2)$. You don't need to find $a$, you need to plug in $a = 1/2$ and $a = 1$ (the limits of the values bounding $A$). Note that $A$ is a random variable, and $a$ is a particular value taken by that random variable.

For part (c) note that a continuous random variable takes an exact value with zero probability -- e.g. $P(A = 1) = 0$. So what is the difference between $P(A \leq 1)$ and $P(A < 1)$?

For part (d) the definition of $F_{A}(a)$ says that $F_{A}(a) = c$ for $a \geq 1$. In this case $a = 2 \geq 1$ so $F_{A}(2) = P(A \leq 2) = c$. So how do you use this to find $P(A > 2)$?

Comment: probability course is complicated itself, and i dont want to mixing it with limit, neither teacher. Can you explain Part (a) in different way ?

Comment: You mean C is just 1 ?

Comment: @Andy Yes, that's it. The limit is the proper way to say that the final value of $F_{A}(a)$ (i.e. when $a$ is very large) is $1$ but it's really quite simple.

Comment: in part D i made a mistake $P(A>2)=1 - F(2) = 0 $ right ?

Comment: @Andy You got it.